# Как получить имя переменной?

Tags: java

Теоретическая задача: есть класс и каждый раз при создании его объектов, этот объект добавляется в статический ArrayList класса
После чего в цикле foreach я перебираю каждый элемент списка объектов и вывожу по шаблону "Объект " + имя_переменной

**Как можно взять имя переменной в данном случае?**

Comment: При выполнении кода компилятор ничего не знает о именах переменных, никак и нигде не хранит их и никаким образом не использует. Имена переменных присутствуют только в исходном коде на этапе написания кода в IDE,после компиляции проекта вся информация о них утрачивается. Ответ - то, что вы хотите невозможно в принципе

Comment: Что такое `имя_переменной` в данном случае? Объясните на примере, какой вывод от вашей программы вы хотите получить.

Comment: @pavlofff, ну для java это не совсем верно, но в целом посыл верный.

Comment: А самому их сохранить тоже не получится? Если имена переменных вам известны, то можно, например, занести их в такой же список. На крайний случай, выводите их порядковый номер

Comment: @RomanKonoval 
Cat cat1 = new cat();
В данном случае cat1 - имя переменной (объекта)
Тут всё просто, но речь о более сложных ситуаций по типу 
Cat barsik = new Cat();

Comment: Ни одно из имен какой-либо из множества переменных, хранящих ссылку на объект, не является именем объекта. Добавляйте поле с именем и геттер в сам объект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь рефлексией и сохраняйте в список имена. Например:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestClass {
    private static List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    private TestClass className = new TestClass();
    private TestClass anotherName = new TestClass();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Field> fields = Arrays.stream(TestClass.class.getDeclaredFields())
                .filter(f -> f.getType().getSimpleName().equals("TestClass"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        fields.forEach(f -> names.add(f.getName()));
        names.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
className
anotherName
```

Comment: Важно чтобы переменная была не локальной